# How do I convert a csh script to python using the subprocess module?

Tags: python, subprocess, csh

How do I run multiple command with  subprocess? What I would like to do, is to use the subprocess module to do the equivalent of the csh script below.

```csh
#!/bin/csh

setenv VARIABLE value
source /folder/license_setup.rc

command -flag0 -arg0a -flag1 -arg1a
command -flag0 -arg0b -flag1 -arg1b
command -flag0 -arg0c -flag1 -arg1c
```

As an intermediate step I tried running script from python.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['source run.csh'], shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
```

This work fine, but it is not yet what I want. I looked at examples, and I think I need to use Popen and communicate, but can't figure out how. I wrote a naive pseudo implementation below. Does anyone have any suggestions?

```py
with subprocess.Popen(..., shell=True, executable='/bin/csh') as proc:
  proc.communicate('setenv VARIABLE value')
  proc.communicate('source /folder/license_setup.rc')
  proc.communicate('command -flag0 -arg0a -flag1 -arg1a')
  proc.communicate('command -flag0 -arg0b -flag1 -arg1b')
  proc.communicate('command -flag0 -arg0c -flag1 -arg1c')
```

As an alternative I could also generate multiple csh scripts and run them separately. But it seems a bit silly to create a bunch of csh scripts and call all of them, as opposed to doing the scripting in python.

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['source runa.csh'], shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
subprocess.run(['source runb.csh'], shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
subprocess.run(['source runc.csh'], shell=True, executable='/bin/csh')
```

(btw: The reason I want to use separate calls is to monitor the progress, with tqdm. I did not include the tqdm statements, to keep the example short.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution using a list of commande to be execute:

```
from subprocess import Popen

commands = [
'setenv VARIABLE value', 
'source /folder/license_setup.rc',
'command -flag0 -arg0a -flag1 -arg1a',
'command -flag0 -arg0b -flag1 -arg1b',
'command -flag0 -arg0c -flag1 -arg1c'
]
procs = [ Popen(i, shell=True, executable='/bin/csh') for i in commands ]
for p in procs:
   p.wait()
```